# How to easily commenting PHP+HTML code

Tags: php, html, comments

Especially for easy and small projects, I leave pure HTML in my PHP source code and I simply add the relevant PHP when needed, and so many times I have something like this:

```
<div class="header-info">
  <p><?php echo $w["emailText"][$lang];?></p>
</div>
```

Now, apart from it being good or bad practice, how can I easily comment out the whole 3 lines?
If I enclose them in HTML comments like these (sorry for the space but otherwise they are not printed):

```
 < !-- 
    ... my code ...
 -->
```

then PHP is still executed. If I enclose them in something like

```
 <?php
   if (0) {
 ?>
   ... my code ...
 <?php
   }
 ?>
```

then the nested "?>" will close my PHP if(0).

Again, I am fully aware that I should better use a Model-View-Controller approach and not mix different "worlds", but as said, for small projects it does not make sense and I am just asking if there is another solution to the 2 that I proposed :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not needed, why not remove it completely? If you want to prevent div tag from outputing to browser, then you can comment all of them, like following.

```
<?php /*
  <div class="header-info">
    <p><?php echo $w["emailText"][$lang];?></p>
  </div>
*/ ?>
```

Comment: Usually it's because I want to see "how it looks like" without that piece of code, so I want to comment/uncomment it at will. I didn't think about the multi line comment in PHP/C style, thank you for that! Sometimes, the easiest solutions are the best :)

Comment: But uhm.. Judging from the SO code parsing, the ?> will close the PHP code... Let me see if it does it in real life too...

Comment: Ok, in "real life" it works :) I will accept the answer as soon as I can :)